# Azure Service Bus Event Grid

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-eventgrid

I am using event grid to trigger an azure function, from message entering the topic it takes 10-15 minutes (no volume 1 message at a time) before event grid picks up the "event" if it ever does and tirggers the function which instantly consumes it.

I am not sure what is happening to that has this massive time delay. Message hits topic --> 10 minutes later ---> event grid fires ----> azure function consumes instantly

Comment: What does it have to do with Service Bus?

Comment: Is this a custom topic or one of the Azure services emitting the event?

Comment: Service bus topic with the event grid inside the service bus that has a subscription to an azure function.

Comment: @Mikhail service bus event grid, not a custom event just the service bus integration with event grid

Comment: Do you have a premium servicebus namespace ???

Comment: yes, it is a premium sb namespace. messaging units dont affect the timing it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be instantaneous for the first message and then only repeated once per minute thereafter.